# Cant play the video Vlc Url scheme IOS

Tags: ios, swift, vlc

I have a video.mp4 and i want to play it on vlc
i am new to swift and this stuff so i dont know if this url scheme is right or wrong

this is the code below

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Video", ofType: "mp4")
    let vlcURL = "vlc://\(path!)"
    let vlcItem = ( URL(string:vlcURL)!)
    UIApplication.shared.open(vlcItem)
```

EDIT: I tried to play a stream and it works
but I want to play a video saved locally how do I do that

EDIT2: I managed to get the URL path to vlc but it when I click play it shows a black screen and closes it

Comment: Where is the video saved to?

Comment: My xcode project in the xcode file

Comment: OK, so if you've got the video yourself in your own app, why don't you just play the video yourself in your own app?

Comment: @matt I don't want that I want to play it in vlc because it has many controllers and more comfortable to watch

Comment: Well, you can't do that. Once the video is in your app, it is _sandboxed_. VLC cannot see it so it cannot play it. You can use an activity to controller to let the _user_ hand it off to any app that can deal with videos and will accept it; but VLC is not one of those.

Comment: @matt ok so that's the problem thank you, but on Filza I can share the file and choose open in do you how to do that?